# How to get the braid word of the tubes in a reducible braid?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, braid-groups

If a braid is reducible, it means that the strands can be separated into groups of strands (less groups than number of strands), such that each group is running inside one tube. The tubes themselves can form a braid.

I am aware of algorithms that determine whether a braid is reducible, implemented for example in flipper. Is it also possible to determine a braid word for the braid that is formed by the tubes? (Perhaps one can get it directly from another output, in that case my understanding is not developed enough to know how.)

Is the special case of determining whether the constituent braid formed of the tubes is trivial implemented somewhere?